# Why doesn't Microsoft Fakes create ShimFtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

Performing the following steps:

- Creating a default WCF Service Library project
- Creating a default Unit Test project and referencing the service library
- Creating a Fakes assembly for System in the unit test project

I was expecting there to be a type `ShimFtpWebRequest` in System.4.0.0.0.Fakes. There is not. Setting the Diagnostics property to true on System.Net.Fakes emits a huge slew of warning messages mostly talking about failure to generate **stubs**, including for `FtpWebRequest` - because those classes are sealed, are enums, and so on. I'm ok with that, and I don't care about stubs, what I want are shims. There is no message saying that it couldn't generate a **shim** type.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282143/how-to-create-a-fake-ftpwebresponse) suggests that there are some scenarios were it is generated, as the OP uses it, but he doesn't mention anything about how he generated it, as it isn't the subject of the question.

Why doesn't Fakes generate the type `ShimFtpWebRequest`?

Comment: The link you provided talks about FtpWebResponse and not FtpWebRequest. Why would you want to shim the request anyway? That seems a little odd to me.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu I acknowledged that in the question, but the linked question **mentions** an FtpWebRequest shim. This demonstrates that it's possible to generate one, given the right settings. I don't understand your question - I want to shim the request because a real FtpWebRequest's behaviour doesn't belong in a unit test; common to the purpose of all shims.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the `System.fakes` file that was generated to tell it to generate the class. I believe it auto ignores sealed classes.

I had the same issue as you when I tested, but then I manually told it to generate it.

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
    <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
    <ShimGeneration>
        <Add FullName="System.Net.FtpWebRequest"/>
    </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Comment: I did find this solution independently in the end, after convincing myself at the first attempt that it didn't work - I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but it took a second go to make this go. This is the correct answer though.